# React - import multiple svgs in a single file

Tags: reactjs, svg, import

I have multiple svg files and I want to import and export all of them in a single file:

```
icons.js

import IconVideoOn from '../../assets/img/icons/video-on.svg';
import IconVideoOff from '../../assets/img/icons/video-off.svg';
import IconMicOn from '../../assets/img/icons/mic-on.svg';
import IconMicOff from '../../assets/img/icons/mic-off.svg';
.
.
.

export default {
    IconVideoOn,
    IconVideoOff,
    IconMicOn,
    IconMicOff
};
```

then I'm importing them like this

```
MyComponent.jsx

import { IconVideoOn } from '../../components/Icons/icons';
```

But I'm getting this error on my component, can't figure out why:

> ./src/components/MyComponent/MyComponent.jsx
> Attempted import error: 'IconVideoOn' is not exported from '../../components/Icons/icons'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant `export default` multiple value type thing.

Either do this:

```
export {
    IconVideoOn,
    IconVideoOff,
    IconMicOn,
    IconMicOff
};
```

then your existing import works

Or do this:

```
const MySVG = {
    IconVideoOn,
    IconVideoOff,
    IconMicOn,
    IconMicOff
};

export default MySVG;
```

Then import like this:

```
import MySVG from '../../components/Icons/icons';
```

and use like this:

```
<img src={MySVG.IconVideoOn} alt=""/>
```