# What is the proper way conditionally require images assets with React Native and TypeScript? (getting eslint errors)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, eslint, javascript-import

Using React Native 0.63 and Typescript 4.

I have an app with categories. Each category has an image that is stored as an asset with the code.

I tried this:

```
myImage = require(`${myImageName}.jpg`)
```

But eslint tells me:

> Calls to require() should use string literals ([eslintimport/no-dynamic-require](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/global-require))

So instead I did this:

In images/index.ts:

```
import vibrators = require('./vibrators.jpg'),
import dildos = require('./dildos.jpg'),
import clitoris = require('./clitoris.jpg'),
import plugs = require('./plugs.jpg'),
import rings = require('./rings.jpg'),
import kits = require('./kits.jpg'),
import men = require('./men.jpg'),
import women = require('./men.jpg'),
import couple = require('./couple.jpg'),
import bondage = require('./bondage.jpg'),
import furniture = require('./funiture.jpg'),
import lingerie = require('./lingerie.jpg'),
import games = require('./games.jpg'),

const categories = {vibrators, dildos, plugs, rings, kits, men, women, couple, bondage, furniture, lingerie, games}

export { categories, ... }
```

(Sorry, I'm tired of changing all names each time I post something about this app... ^-^')

In my component that prints categories images:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { categories } from '../assets/images'

interface Props {
  category: string
}

const CategoryImage: FC<Props> = ({ category }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation()

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={() => navigation.navigate(category)}>
      <Image source={categories[category]} style={styles.image} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export default CategoryImage
```

But there again, on:

```
import vibrators = require('./vibrators.jpg'),
```

I have:

> Require statement not part of import statement. ([eslint@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v2.34.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-var-requires.md))

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647648/react-import-multiple-svgs-in-a-single-file/63647704#63647704) answer help you?

Comment: Thanks. Actually I can't get ride of this "Require statement not part of import statement" but this is only an eslint error and works well whatsoever...